# Looking for the name of a little known solitaire card game

Tags: identify-this-game

My aunt taught me this form of solitaire game, she was from the west coast state of Washington and taught it to me some 40 yrs ago. Here are the rules:

Single player,
Single deck,
No jokers,
Shuffle deck.

If matching card is not side by side you have to have 2 spaces between to match.

The object of the game is to get all the cards back into a pile going from right to left (in this case the k❤️ would be the bottom card in the deck).

Lay out 4 cards side by side and look for a match either in number or suit. Going in a backwards direction match the last card with the next available match. So say you put down k❤️,10♦️,6♣️,6♠️. You can match and put the 6♠️ on top of the 6♣️. You can't go on so now starting with one card at a time put the next card at the end say it's a Q❤️ for example. You can take that Q❤️ and put it on the k❤️ because there are 2 spaces. For example if it was a Q♦️ you would have to leave it as the last card in line because there is only one space btwn Q♦️ and 10♦️. Put down next card say it's a 2♦️ now you have choice to either put it on the 10♦️ because has 2 places OR put it on top of the Q♦️, but per the object of the game it's best to put it on top of the 10♦️. Your row of cards would look like this, k❤️,2♦️,6♠️, Q♦️, now put next card down..... And so on. Keep going till the end of the deck in your hand. It's not easy to win I've only done it maybe 3 or 4 times.

Hope that made all made sense

Comment: I'd really like to know the name to see if I could play it in an app online, if it even exists that is. Thank you to everyone who's viewed my post so far

Answer (score 2):

This is *Accordion* patience.  There are a few variants around, such as whether you are obliged to make a move if one is available or whether a move can be deferred until a later time or, to give another rule variant, in the case that a move is available to both an adjacent pile or the separated pile whether one of the moves is forced.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much for the name, I love playing this form of solitaire! I've played it for close to 40 yrs never knowing it's name, LOL. Now to go search the play store to see if it's out there in an app thanks again!